# Preprocess function for body field?

Tags: theming

I have a client with a D8 site who wants curly quotes and apostrophes on all rendered content. I was able to do this for the page titles with this preprocess function:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
// Load the node entity from the current route
if ($node = \Drupal::request()->get('node')) {

    // Get the title
    $title = $node->getTitle();

    // Replace left quotes
    $title = preg_replace('/"(?=\w)/', '&ldquo;', $title);

    // Replace right quotes
    $title = preg_replace('/(?<=\w)"/', '&rdquo;', $title);

    // Replace single quote/apostrophe
    $title = str_replace("'", '&rsquo;', $title);

    // Return the title variable
    $variables['title'] = t($title);
}
}
```

Is there a way to do this for the body field as well? hook_preprocess_field isn't getting me anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a preprocess function, you could accomplish the desired behavior using CSS.

Using the [`::before`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) and [`::after`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) selectors you can insert additional content. This content could be the textual " character (i.e., `content: '"';`) or you could display it as an (inline-)block, provide width, height, margin and padding and set a background image.

For example:

```
.field--name-body {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.field--name-body::before {
  content: '"';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.field--name-body::after {
  content: '"';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This creates some space around the body field and provides " characters at the top left and bottom right location.

Comment: I think I might not have been clear in my initial post. I need to replace plain text quotation marks in the body text with smart quotes: `&rdquo;` and `&ldquo;`, and straight apostrophes need to be replaced with `&rsquo;`. Your solution will only add plain quotation marks around the entire body field.